# Specify dependencies for inclusion in nupkg

Tags: f#, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to release a library on nuget, but when trying to install it, it says that it can't find the dependency.

I'm using `paket` and a `paket.template` in order to generate the `nupkg`. I have no real idea how dependency resolution happens in F#/.NET, but it looks like in my `.fsproj` file, it's referencing a relative path.

The dependency I'm trying to include is `Colorful.Console`.

In my `.fsproj`, it references it like:

```
<Reference Include="Colorful.Console">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Colorful.Console\lib\net461\Colorful.Console.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Paket>True</Paket>
</Reference>
```

which works fine locally, and seems to have no apparent problems during `paket pack`, but when installing in a different project from the remote source (also using `paket`), it tells me that `MyLibrary can't find dependency 'Colorful.Console'`.

It's in my library's dependencies with `nuget Colorful.Console`, and that dependency seems to be carried through, as `Colorful.Console` is in the `packages` folder of my other project (and shows up under 'References' in Visual Studio).

I've included the example project here: https://github.com/deecewan/GenbankDemoProject

[Here](https://github.com/deecewan/GenbankTypeProvider/blob/feature/nupkg) is the library project, and more directly the [`paket.template`](https://github.com/deecewan/GenbankTypeProvider/blob/feature/nupkg/GenbankTypeProvider/paket.template) used to generate the package.

Edit: I have updated my project thanks to advice from @rmunn - it is now meant to load the `Colorful.Console` version from `net461` when the framework is `net472`. This is what I want/expect, I think. However, I still get the following error:

```
parse error FS3053: error : The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Colorful.Console, Version=1.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Attached below is a screenshot of the references of the project - `GenbankTypeProvider` and `Colorful.Console` are both included.

[image: references]

Comment: I don't see a [`paket.template` file](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html) in your project, so when you do `paket pack` it creates a NuGet package that does not list its dependencies. Short version: the spec for NuGet files includes a dependency list, which says "this package relies on package ABC to run". To create a proper dependency list when using Paket, you need to either create a `paket.template` file, or else run `paket pack --include-referenced-projects` to create a NuGet file with the package dependencies properly listed.

Comment: @rmunn that is the project that is *consuming* the library - the `paket.template` file from the library project is the exact same as https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html#Example-1

Comment: @rmunn I have updated the question to include links to the library and the paket.template.

Comment: Then I think the issue is this one. From the [documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html#Dependencies): "In a project file, the following dependencies will be added: [...] Any Paket dependency **with the range specified** in the paket.dependencies file." (Emphasis mine). Your `paket.dependencies` file doesn't specify a target version range for Colorful.Console, so Colorful.Console isn't included in the NuGet package dependency list. Include a version range (`nuget Colorful.Console ~> 1.2`) and it should start being included in the dependencies of the NuGet package.

Comment: BTW, the reason for this rule in Paket is (as I understand it) so that you can provide a safe dependency range in your NuGet package. E.g., your package that's built against Colorful.Console 1.x might fail against Colorful.Console 2.x because they make a breaking API change, so Paket requires you to have at least thought about the possibility before releasing your package.

Comment: @rmunn that makes sense (like, I understand the rationale behind what you're saying), but the `GenbankDemoProject` actually creates a dependency to `Colorful.Console` (without me adding it to `paket.dependencies`) so I'm confused why `GenbankTypeProvider` can't find it.

Comment: In fact, looking at the [nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GenbankTypeProvider/) it seems to include the dependency on Colorfule.Console.

Comment: So I was wrong about the NuGet package. However, looking at your `GenbankDemoProject.fsproj` I'm spotting another issue. At the top of the file you specify `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`. In the references list of the .fsproj file, there are a bunch of conditional references. [The one targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2](https://github.com/deecewan/GenbankDemoProject/blob/3b2ce19483e6e2fcb4248f7f9eccaf805a319fe1/GenbankDemoProject/GenbankDemoProject.fsproj#L189) does *not* include Colorful.Console.

Comment: Ah! You're correct. `Colorful.Console` seems to only work with net461 - I think I've seen online how to force it to use the older version regardless. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I think this is because Colorful.Console does not have a build targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. It *does* have a build targeting .NET Standard 2.0, so if you build your project to target that one (which .NET Framework 4.7.2 implements) then your Colorful.Console reference should work. And if you're confused about the .NET Standard vs. .NET Framework versioning, join the club! It's NOT at all intuitive. You'll want to bookmark [this table](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) and consult it frequently.